# How to scroll through a drop-down menu with Selenium Webdriver in Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I need to move through this menu until I get to the "Generate" option.

I am doing it from Excel VBA. Until now I did it with

```
bot.ExecuteScript ("on_load_form('v_aux_presupuesto.php','',false,false,false,false,'app');")
```

but now it does not work for me. Is there some code to be able to move through the menu to that option? I can not do it in any way ...

Here is the webpage's menu code:

[image]

Comment: "_Until now I did it with [...] but now it does not work for me_"... can you please be more specific? What was working before and it's not working now exactly?
As a side note, if you could copy-paste the HTML code instead of a screenshot it would be probably better.

Comment: Also, if you explain where you really want to go, there's probably a better solution than robotically scrolling down a dropdown menu.

Comment: please share the url if possible

Comment: When I click in "Generar", it opens a window where I have to fill a form, before I did it with bot.ExecuteScript ("on_load_form('v_aux_presupuesto.php','',false,false,false,false,'app');") but it does not work right now. I can not share the url because it is private (user and password)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to get the parent element then descendant combinator to get the child `a` tag for click

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[data-title='Generar un presupuesto'] a").Click
```